# Address control for web based email application

Tags: asp.net, controls, user-interface

I am looking for a control to add email addresses for a mailing application. I am not sure what it is called but I saw something similar to it at staples "Share This" link. It should allow to add email address by typing or delete it by clicking the X on its right. Could you please let me know if there are any existing controls for it or how should one create it. Thanks.

Sample

http://img4.yfrog.com/img4/6640/sharethisk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [TextBoxList](http://devthought.com/projects/mootools/textboxlist/)

[image]
<sub>(source: [devthought.com](http://devthought.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/04/picture-1.png))</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the link Eduardo, this will help me what to search for.